# Postgres `WITH ins AS ...` casting everything as text

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have this table in postgres

```
CREATE TABLE target (
    a json
    b integer
    c text []
    id integer
    CONSTRAINT id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES public.other_table(id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
)
```

Which I would like to insert data to from psycopg2 using

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras as extras

# data is of the form dict, integer, list(string), string <- used to get fkey id
data = [[extras.Json([{'a':1,'b':2}, {'d':3,'e':2}]), 1, ['hello', 'world'], 'ident1'],
        [extras.Json([{'a':4,'b':3}, {'d':1,'e':9}]), 5, ['hello2', 'world2'], 'ident2']]


# convert data to list of tuples containing objects
x = [tuple(u) for u in data]

# insert data to the database
query = ('WITH ins (a, b, c, ident) AS '
         '(VALUES %s) '
         'INSERT INTO target (a, b, c, id) '
         'SELECT '
            'ins.a '
            'ins.b '
            'ins.c '
            'other_table.id'
        'FROM '
            'ins '
            'LEFT JOIN other_table ON ins.ident = other_table.ident;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

extras.execute_values(cursor, query, data)
```

When I run this as is I get the error: `column "a" is of type json but expression is of type text`

I tried to solve this by adding a type cast in the SELECT statement

```
         'SELECT '
            'ins.a::json '
            'ins.b '
            'ins.c '
            'other_table.id'
```

but then I get the error `column "c" is of type text[] but expression is of type text`

So I fixed that in the same way:

```
         'SELECT '
            'ins.a::json '
            'ins.b '
            'ins.c::text[]'
            'other_table.id'
```

so now I am getting the error `column "b" is of type integer but expression is of type text`

This example is somewhat simplified as I have many more columns in the original query.

1. Does the `WITH ins ...` statement always convert everything to text? This seems like an odd behavior to me
2. Is there a way to code this without having to manually typecast every column? This seems inelegant and computationally inefficient data gets converted eg. from python int to postgres text to postgres integer.

Comment: As @Jim Jones pointed out the problem does not lie with the WITH statement like this question was assuming. I therefore reformulated the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67792770/psycopg2-execute-values-sending-all-values-as-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html), but with how you're passing values into the `VALUES` clause. Somehow all values created inside of the `CTE` at `VALUES` are being sent as text (perhaps the query is created with all values between single quotes?). The following example reproduces your query with pure SQL statements, and it works as it should:

```
WITH ins (a, b, c, id) AS (
  VALUES ('{"answer":42}'::json,42,array['foo','bar'],1)
) 
INSERT INTO target (a,b,c,id)
SELECT ins.a,ins.b,ins.c,other_table.id 
FROM ins 
LEFT JOIN other_table ON ins.id = other_table.id;
```

Note that I cast the json the value inside of the `CTE`, not in the `SELECT` clause. So, if the origin is correct, there is no way that postgres will cast it to text without you telling it to do so ;)

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3749c0b630b364106f8b2e29b45d0b4a)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this already helps a lot! Would anything in the SQL code above explain why the Values in the CTE are being sent as text? If not then the only thing I could imagine is `execute_values`

Comment: I honestly don't know much about python, so I cannot tell why it behaves like this. But I could bet that the values are being sent to the server between single quotes, e.g. `'1'` instead of `1`, which postgres will see as `text`.

Comment: Ok I will investigate the python side but you don't see a problem in my sql statement right?

Comment: @sev no, I see no problem with your sql code. In my fiddle you can see I reproduced your environment and it works just fine. Try to find out what is actually being sent to the server, I mean how the sql looks like.

Comment: I think it makes sense to reformulate this question  with this information so I will mark this as the answer and open a new one.