# Psycopg2 execute_values sending all values as text

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have this table in postgres

```
CREATE TABLE target (
    a json
    b integer
    c text []
    id integer
    CONSTRAINT id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES public.other_table(id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
)
```

Which I would like to insert data to from psycopg2 using

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras as extras

# data is of the form dict, integer, list(string), string <- used to get fkey id
data = [[extras.Json([{'a':1,'b':2}, {'d':3,'e':2}]), 1, ['hello', 'world'], 'ident1'],
        [extras.Json([{'a':4,'b':3}, {'d':1,'e':9}]), 5, ['hello2', 'world2'], 'ident2']]


# convert data to list of tuples containing objects
x = [tuple(u) for u in data]

# insert data to the database
query = ('WITH ins (a, b, c, ident) AS '
         '(VALUES %s) '
         'INSERT INTO target (a, b, c, id) '
         'SELECT '
            'ins.a '
            'ins.b '
            'ins.c '
            'other_table.id'
        'FROM '
            'ins '
            'LEFT JOIN other_table ON ins.ident = other_table.ident;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

extras.execute_values(cursor, query, x)
```

When I run this I get the `error: column "a" is of type json but expression is of type text`. I tried to solve this by adding a type cast in the SELECT statement but then I got the same error for c and then for b.

Originally I thought the problem lies in the WITH statement but based on the answers to my previous question this seems to not be the case [Postgres `WITH ins AS ...` casting everything as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790537/postgres-with-ins-as-casting-everything-as-text)

It seems that `execute_values` is sending all the values as text with `' '`.

***Main Question:* How can I get `execute_values` to send the values based on their python data type rather than just as text?**

Sub questions: 
How can I confirm that `execute_values` is in fact sending the values as text with quotation marks?
What is the purpose of the template argument of `execute_values` https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html and could that be of help?

Comment: This: `x = [tuple(u) for u in data]` unnecessary.  The `(VALUES %s)`  collects the inputs as text as there are no types specified. You will need you `CAST` each of `SELECT` occurrences to the correct type.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver You say there are no types specified, how can I specify the types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue, as [Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) points out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67792770/psycopg2-execute-values-sending-all-values-as-text#comment119827481_67792770), and also seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677252/5320906), is that the typing is lost in the CTE.

We can show this with an example in the `psql` shell:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (col1 json);

WITH cte (c) AS (VALUES ('{"a": 1}'))
INSERT INTO test (col) SELECT c FROM cte;
```

resulting in

```
ERROR:  column "col" is of type json but expression is of type text
```

whereas this version, with the type specified, succeeds:

```sql
WITH cte(c)  AS  (VALUES ('{"a": 1}'::json))
INSERT INTO test (col) SELECT c FROM cte;
```

We can mimic this in `execute_values`by providing the typing information in the template argument:

```py
extras.execute_values(cursor, query, data, template='(%s::json, %s, %s, %s)')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When using the template, is execute values first casting the data to string and then to the appropriate type or does it convert directly? Also do I need to specify the datatype for all types except string or would e.g. int be automatic as would be indicated by your example? Also, is it the same for e.g. executemany?

Comment: I don't know enough about the innards of psycopg2 to say, but I can tell you that the above statement succeeded for me using you DDL and data (though I didn't bother with the FK part).  So it seems Postgresql needs to be told about the JSON, but an infer the other types.

Comment: I've reworked the answer a little to demonstrate that the issue is in Postgresql, rather than psycopg2.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is on the postgres side? In the first example you give in your answer, the Values `'{"a": 1}'` are in fact text - they are not json so I would expect this error. We aren't doing any type casting and we aren't getting any type casting. However when using the psycopg2 extras.Json datatype I would expect no typecasting to be necessary, yet somehow this gets converted to text. This is additionally unexpected since extras_values seems to do fine with other data types.

Comment: Yes - `INSERT INTO test (col) VALUES ('{"a": 1}')` inserts without error, so the issue must be in how Postgresql is [inferring](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-union-case.html) the type in the `VALUES` clause in the CTE.